# How to exclude query params from url regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to the way we group pages in mPulse, and have been running into an issue with the regexes for the page groups.

Essentally the url of each becon gets mapped to a page group and i cant seems to get the mapping correct. To improve my ability to test this and ilustrate the issue i have extracted into js to that i can easly run it.

However, i can sumuries the issues as following:
When using the regexed described bellow i cant get the desired results. I want to only focus on the url before the query param and ignore everything that comes after. But the query params is causing the page group to produce undesired results:

This is the ilustration of the issue and description of the underlining problem.

So i got these to regexes:

```js
const pageGroupDefs = {
    r: 6,
    regex: /(https:\/\/[a-z.-].*)\/(en)\/([^\/^\?^\#]+)?\/?$/,
    viewGroup: "en - $3"
  },
  {
    r: 7,
    regex: /(https:\/\/[a-z.-].*)\/(en)\/([^\/^\?^\#]+)?\/?([^\/^\?^\#]+)?\/?([^\/^\?^\#]+)?(\?\S*)?/,
    viewGroup: "en - $3 - $4"
  }
];
```

And i pass them though this method to extract the date:

```js
function getPageGroup(url, pGD) {
  for (const def of pGD) {
    const match = def.regex.exec(url);
    if (match) {
      // Use the matched groups to format the viewGroup
      return {
        matched: def.r,
        pageGroup: def.viewGroup.replace(/\$(\d+)/g, (_, group) => match[group]),
        url: url
      }
    }
  }
  return {matched: null,pageGroup: null, url: url};
}
```

and i got this list of urls:

```
const urlExamples = [
  'https://example.com/en/path',
  'https://example.com/en/path/',
  'https://example.com/en/path?param=example',
  'https://example.com/en/path/?param=example',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/subpath2',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/subpath3/subpath3',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath?param=example',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/?param=example',
  'https://example.com/en/path?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2',
  'https://example.com/en/path/?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2',
  'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2',
  'https://www.sub-domain.domain.co.uk/en/path/sub-path?param1=val1&param2=https://www.sub-domain.domain.co.uk/en/path&param3=val3&param4=val4',
];
```

So if I test the regex running:

```js
const regexResults = urlExamples.forEach(i => getPageGroup(url, pageGroupDefs));
console.log(regexResults);
```

This will produce this results:

```js
[
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path'
  },
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - undefined',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - undefined',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/subpath3/subpath3'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path2 - subpath2',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path2 - subpath2',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path2 - subpath2',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path2 - subpath2',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path&param3=val3&param4=val4',
    url: 'https://www.sub-domain.domain.co.uk/en/path/sub-path?param1=val1&param2=https://www.sub-domain.domain.co.uk/en/path&param3=val3&param4=val4'
  }
]
```

And the result i expect and want it this one:

```js
[
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path'
  },
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/'
  },
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/subpath3/subpath3'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/?param=example'
  },
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 6,
    pageGroup: 'en - path',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://example.com/en/path/subpath/?param=https://example2.com/en/path2/subpath2'
  },
  {
    matched: 7,
    pageGroup: 'en - path - subpath',
    url: 'https://www.sub-domain.domain.co.uk/en/path/sub-path?param1=val1&param2=https://www.sub-domain.domain.co.uk/en/path&param3=val3&param4=val4'
  }
]
```

Comment: Create a `URL`  object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not have the ability to do that. The only thing i can change is the pageGroupDefs